# Table metadata lock MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, myisam

I'm having serious problems in a DB, where a "Waiting for table level lock" box is loitering and locks the whole system:

[image]

Based on some research, when the problem occurred to get the command "SELECT * FROM information_schema.metadata_lock_info;" and the result was:
[image]

continue 
[image]

One DB engine is MyIsam.

What could be happening? I have 50 simultaneous accesses on average.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We use only English here. Please edit and translate your question to English.

Answer (score 1):

Table-level locks exist with MyISAM; they are avoided with InnoDB.  Change the ENGINE.

"Metadata" locks can happen with either Engine.

In the first image, what is the *entire* query at the top of the list?  Please provide it in machine-readable format, not as a picture.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s).  Perhaps we can help you speed up the query.  It has been running 78 seconds and is probably blocking the rest of the connections.